# Can I charge a Sony Cybershot DSC-T200 using a computer's USB port?

Tags: sony, usb, charger

The Sony Cybershot DSC-T200 comes with an external wall mounted charger for its proprietary battery. Some Sony cameras allow you to draw power from a computer's USB port.  Is this possible with the DSC-T200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Page 35 of [the manual](http://docs.sony.com/release/DSCT70.pdf), the battery can only be charged in the charger, not in the camera.

(note: the linked manual says DSCT70.pdf in the link, but the manual covers 3 versions including the T200).

Comment: I understand per the manual the battery can only be charged in charger not in the camera, as there is no provision built in to charge. But some adverts show that a data cable with a bulged capacitor-like joint exist. Then is it possible that the battery can be charged in the camera by using such a data cable?